# FFmpeg: building example C codes

Tags: c, makefile, ffmpeg, compilation, libav

I have configured and compiled the FFmpeg library using this link:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Now, I am trying to build example C codes provided by FFmpeg from here:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples

However, when I run make install-examples or make install (suggested by /example/README), I receive this kind of message:

> make: *** No rule to make target '/doc/examples/README', needed by
>   'install-examples'.  Stop.

I thought this may be due to the rules not being in the correct MakeFile format (I am not sure why they refers to README). How should I go about in fixing this and compiling the example codes? I have tried to find solutions about this, but there doesn't seem to be much information online.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use `make examples`, or just `make` ...

Comment: I have tried those as well, but they output similar message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `./configure && make -j4 examples` in the FFmpeg source directory, then look in `doc/examples` for the compiled examples.

- Requires `make` and `pkg-config`.
- To remove the compiled examples use `make examplesclean` in the FFmpeg source directory.

Comment: Thanks very much @llogan for the helpful answer. This worked perfectly after I had struggled for hours on this problem. Are you able to explain why this is necessary to help with further compiling as I would like to modify some of the examples and compile and I would very much like to streamline the process.

Answer (score 0):

nasm/yasm not found or too old. Use --disable-x86asm for a crippled build. If you think to configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to theffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help solve the problem.

If you see this when you execute the above command then do this 



macOS:
brew install yasm

Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install yasm