# Trouble linking own application using ffmpeg/libav

Tags: c, ffmpeg, linker-errors, libav

I have a source, that I'd like to build and link against the libav library on Linux. 
I followed the compilation guide of ffmpeg here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
Everything works.
I build the included examples like this: [FFmpeg: building example C codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031918/ffmpeg-building-example-c-codes)
It also works.

Now, I'd like to build my own little applications, where I try to learn about using libav. My current problem is, that by using the command line

```
gcc muxing.c -g -I ../../../ffmpeg_build/include/ -L ../../../ffmpeg_build/lib/ -lavdevice -lavformat -lavfilter -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm -lz -lpthread -lfdk-aac -lmp3lame -lx264 -lva -lX11
```

I get to this point:

```
muxing.c: In function ‘write_audio_frame’:
muxing.c:354:5: warning: ‘avcodec_encode_audio2’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(codecContext, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
     ^~~
In file included from ../../../ffmpeg_build/include/libavformat/avformat.h:317:0,
                 from muxing.c:42:
../../../ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:5418:5: note: declared here
 int avcodec_encode_audio2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *avpkt,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
muxing.c: In function ‘write_video_frame’:
muxing.c:524:5: warning: ‘avcodec_encode_video2’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ret = avcodec_encode_video2(codecContext, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
     ^~~
In file included from ../../../ffmpeg_build/include/libavformat/avformat.h:317:0,
                 from muxing.c:42:
../../../ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:5457:5: note: declared here
 int avcodec_encode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *avpkt,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libx264.a(opencl-8.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I read, in order to overcome this linker error, I have to append -ldl to my command line, but then I get this:

```
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o): In function `libopus_flush':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:204: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_ctl'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o): In function `libopus_decode':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:169: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decode_float'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:165: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decode'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:174: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o): In function `libopus_decode_close':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:145: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_destroy'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o): In function `libopus_decode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:101: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_create'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:105: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:111: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:113: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:126: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c:129: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o): In function `libopus_encode':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:487: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encode'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:483: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encode_float'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:492: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o): In function `libopus_encode_close':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:530: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_destroy'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o): In function `libopus_encode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:348: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_create'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:358: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_surround_encoder_create'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:365: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o): In function `libopus_configure_encoder':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:121: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:123: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:128: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:131: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:134: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:136: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:139: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:142: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:145: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:148: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:153: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:156: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:161: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:164: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o): In function `libopus_encode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:410: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:412: undefined reference to `opus_strerror'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c:426: undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_destroy'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisenc.o): In function `libvorbis_encode_frame':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:287: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_buffer'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:294: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_wrote'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:310: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_blockout'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:311: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:313: undefined reference to `vorbis_bitrate_addblock'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:317: undefined reference to `vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:302: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_wrote'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisenc.o): In function `libvorbis_encode_close':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:180: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_wrote'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:182: undefined reference to `vorbis_block_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:183: undefined reference to `vorbis_dsp_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:184: undefined reference to `vorbis_info_clear'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisenc.o): In function `libvorbis_encode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:203: undefined reference to `vorbis_info_init'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisenc.o): In function `libvorbis_setup':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:98: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_setup_vbr'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:107: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_setup_managed'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:114: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:121: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:127: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_ctl'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:160: undefined reference to `vorbis_encode_setup_init'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisenc.o): In function `libvorbis_encode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:208: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_init'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:214: undefined reference to `vorbis_block_init'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:220: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_init'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:222: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_add_tag'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:224: undefined reference to `vorbis_analysis_headerout'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisenc.c:257: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_clear'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:161: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_decode'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vpx_decode':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:221: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_frame'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:162: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:163: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error_detail'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:161: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_decode'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:162: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vpx_decode':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:222: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_frame'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:201: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_dx_algo'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:201: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp8_dx_algo'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vpx_free':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:269: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_destroy'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:271: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_destroy'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vpx_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:53: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_version_str'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:54: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_build_config'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:56: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_dec_init_ver'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:59: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vp8_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:278: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp8_dx_algo'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o): In function `vp9_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxdec.c:298: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_dx_algo'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vpx_encode':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:1118: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_encode'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:1126: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_encode'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `queue_frames':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:979: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_cx_data'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:981: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_cx_data'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `log_encoder_error':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:164: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:165: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_error_detail'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `codecctl_int':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:298: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_control_'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vpx_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:524: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_caps'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:527: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_version_str'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:528: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_build_config'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:533: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_enc_config_default'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:534: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_err_to_string'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:719: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_enc_init_ver'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:727: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_enc_init_ver'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:812: undefined reference to `vpx_img_wrap'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:820: undefined reference to `vpx_img_wrap'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vp8_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:1279: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp8_cx'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vp9_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:1309: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_cx'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `codecctl_intp':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:320: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_control_'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o): In function `vpx_free':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:344: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_destroy'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpxenc.c:346: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_destroy'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libx265.o): In function `libx265_encode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx265.c:84: undefined reference to `x265_api_get_173'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx265.c:86: undefined reference to `x265_api_get_173'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libx265.o): In function `libx265_encode_init_csp':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx265.c:494: undefined reference to `x265_api_get_173'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx265.c:496: undefined reference to `x265_api_get_173'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx265.c:498: undefined reference to `x265_api_get_173'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvpx.o): In function `ff_vp9_init_static':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpx.c:73: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_vp9_cx'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvpx.c:73: undefined reference to `vpx_codec_get_caps'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisdec.o): In function `oggvorbis_decode_close':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:191: undefined reference to `vorbis_block_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:192: undefined reference to `vorbis_dsp_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:193: undefined reference to `vorbis_info_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:194: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_clear'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisdec.o): In function `oggvorbis_decode_frame':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:169: undefined reference to `vorbis_synthesis'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:175: undefined reference to `vorbis_synthesis_pcmout'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:179: undefined reference to `vorbis_synthesis_read'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:170: undefined reference to `vorbis_synthesis_blockin'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisdec.o): In function `oggvorbis_decode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:48: undefined reference to `vorbis_info_init'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:49: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_init'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:97: undefined reference to `vorbis_synthesis_headerin'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisdec.o): In function `oggvorbis_decode_close':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:191: undefined reference to `vorbis_block_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:192: undefined reference to `vorbis_dsp_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:193: undefined reference to `vorbis_info_clear'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:194: undefined reference to `vorbis_comment_clear'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisdec.o): In function `oggvorbis_decode_init':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:109: undefined reference to `vorbis_synthesis_init'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libvorbisdec.c:110: undefined reference to `vorbis_block_init'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavutil.a(hwcontext_vaapi.o): In function `vaapi_device_create':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:1490: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplay'
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:1514: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplayDRM'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavutil.a(hwcontext_vaapi.o): In function `vaapi_device_derive':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:1561: undefined reference to `vaGetDisplayDRM'
../../../ffmpeg_build/lib//libavutil.a(hwcontext_vdpau.o): In function `vdpau_device_create':
/home/ritter/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.c:461: undefined reference to `vdp_device_create_x11'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, what can I do, to get it compiled and linked fully?

Comment: Add `-lopus -lopusfile`, (probably both are needed, or probably only one is needed.) to make the command look like `gcc muxing.c -g -I ../../../ffmpeg_build/include/ -L ../../../ffmpeg_build/lib/ -lopus -lopusfile -lavdevice -lavformat -lavfilter -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm -lz -lpthread -lfdk-aac -lmp3lame -lx264 -lva -lX11 -ldl` p.s. it could also just be a case of reordering the linked libraries. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) for more on that.

Comment: Unfortunately it says "cannot find -lopusfile"... What library am I missing? (-lopus alone does not solve the linker issue...)

Comment: Did you try reordering the libraries? Maybe that is the issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) question to understand what I mean.

Comment: I tried a little of reordering already. It didn't help yet, but I certainly do not have tried all the possibilities. I belive it's the issue that I'm facing, but without deeper knowledge of the code base and all the included libriaries in ffmpeg, do I even have a chance to figure this out by myself?
Thanks for the link. Certainly a worthy read.

Comment: I just wonder how you could compile the examples, and at that point there was not linker or compiler error. But now with your own code, you get a linker error. I'd reduce your "own code" to as simple as possible, basically a "hello world" program of "ffmepg" and then compile/build. Or maybe start from one of the examples and add your code to it and see if any error pops up.

Comment: The file I'd like to compile is heavily based on the muxing.c example of ffmpeg, which compiles fine when I do compile all examples of ffmpeg with the initial mentioned command "./configure && make -j4 examples". I think, configure is setting up everything correctly. Unfortunately, analyzing the resulting makefile does not make any sense to me.
It does compile correctly with only some deprecated warnings. The linking is the main problem here, and I just don't understand all the dependencies of ffmpeg/libav based programs, so that I have really issues to set the linker options up correctly.